# Washing and Bentching

Tags: riddle, blessing

Who washes and Bentches but does not eat?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having thought more about this.  I decided that based on the Yiddish meaning of Bentching, everyone who is old enough to say Asher Yatzar does.  Because you wash and then bentch Asher Yatzar.  I am leaving my original answer as well.

Everyone who follows the rulings of the Ben Ish Hai who says to wash ones hands and make a Berakha on besamim before each of the three prayer services(actual source in sefer Ben Ish Hai, and its derivative from Sha'ar HaKavvanot to follow once I look them up).

Answer (score 2):

The Kohanim by Birchas Kohanim

Answer (score 1):

Does drinking count as eating? There is certainly an opinion that one bentches birkat hamazon after wine, and I think there is an opinion to wash before wine, certainly terumah in days of bais hamikdash

Answer (score 1):

Mikva.  (This is to add more characters so I can post)

Comment: Though actually, women are advised to eat something shortly afterwards.  Though that's wash-bensch-eat ....

Comment: Never heard that.  Our minhag is just to touch the mikva lady.

Comment: http://hadassahsabo.wordpress.com/2010/07/14/why-do-they-have-candy-at-the-mikvah/